# Unload from Redshift to an S3 bucket of a box

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to unload data from a Redshift cluster in one box to an S3 bucket in another box.
I have managed to send the file.
However,
as the bucket owner is not the owner of the file I'm sending - he cannot access it.
As it's a straight unload from Redshift, I don't think I can't specify condition to allow the bucket owner the right permissions.

Is it even possible to achieve (without having to unload from Redshift using the same account)
and if so  - how?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a "box" in this context?

Comment: An AWS server. I'm trying to unload into a different account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Attempt #2...)

Okay, it seems your situation is:

- You are doing an `UNLOAD` from Amazon Redshift into an Amazon S3 bucket that belongs to a different AWS Account
- A user within that different AWS Account wishes to access the files but says that they are unable to do so

There is no concept of a "file owner" in Amazon S3. Instead, there are:

- Permissions associated with each object in Amazon S3
- A bucket policy that applies to a specific bucket
- IAM policies that can be applied to Users, Groups and Roles

As long as at least one of these permissions grants access and none of them specifically deny access, then users will be able to access the files.

If the user reports not being able to view the files, then ensure that `ListBucket` and `GetObject` permissions have been granted via one of the above methods.

Comment: Thank you for your help, John!

Comment: @user2518751 were you able to solve this? I am in  the same boat. In my case I am the bucket owner who can't access the object written to my bucket by a Redshift cluster that isn't owned by me. I tried setting the correct Bucket Policy but it didn't work. How did you do it?

Comment: @user2518751, feel free to create a new question if you require asssistance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your situation is:

- You have used the `UNLOAD` command to export data from Amazon Redshift to an Amazon S3 bucket that you own
- You wish to grant access to the files to an AWS user that belongs to a different AWS account

Permission to access an object in Amazon S3 can be granted in several ways:

- **On the object itself**, by manually setting permissions on the file(s)
- **In IAM (Identity and Access Management)**, by attaching a Policy to a specific user that grants permission to access a bucket - but this would only work for users in the same AWS Account
- **By defining a Bucket Policy** that grants access to bucket content, either to everyone (public) or to particular AWS users (including a user in a different account) - the user would need to access the content by supplying credentials, such as using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command.

The Bucket Policy option seems the best for your situation. To enable it, create a policy on the bucket that grants access to a particular directory where you will put the files, for example:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Sid1",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/username"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Sid2",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/PATH/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/username"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The `ARN` in the policy refers to the Account ID and username of the person to whom you are granting access. They can then use the AWS CLI to list the contents of the bucket and download content.

Comment: Sorry for not being more precise. I do not upload data to my bucket, but rather, I upload data straight to a bucket I don't own, on a different account. I know how to handle the scenario you've suggested. The thing is, I don't use my bucket as a temp station between Redshift in my cluster and S3 in the other account. This is why I struggle.